# Does transmutation of 2 items always result in a soul-bound item?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Are there any cases where transmuting results in a non soul-bound item? I'm trying to figure out a way to get a particular look of a skin to another character. For example, the starter medium armor hooded skin of a thief to say a ranger.

Comment: I believe that transmutation, unlike mystic forge crafting, always results in soul bound items. The fact that you can transmute soul bound/account bound items seems to confirm this. (IE transmuting karma items to sell on AH)

Comment: There is apparently [some transmuting process](http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/58988-thief-hood-sollution/page__st__90) that will leave you with a 'soulbound' item that will be available to the two characters involved in the process (i.e. getting your ranger to buy a mask, putting it in the bank for the thief to transmute the starting hood, etc)

Comment: So you're ideally looking for an account bound item? Perhaps you could try transmuting using the HoM items, and then transmuting again? As the HoM items are Account Bound and it might carry across, maybe.

Comment: @DavidYell Can you give an example how this would work with the example I'm trying to do in my last sentence? It's not really clear what you mean.

Comment: Just transmute the target item with a HoM skin, then try transmuting it with the actual skin you want. If the HoM item becomes SoulBound you'll know it won't work. I guess you'd have to buy it off the Trade Post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: They've changed some transmutations to result in account-bound items, as long as the item that determines the stats or the resulting item is not soulbound.

I've preserved my previous answer below:

---

Yes, transmutation will always result in a soulbound item.

On the other hand, you can transmute weapons that are soulbound to other characters. So if you pass the item through your bank, you should be able to transmute it on the desired character.

Comment: Do you have any references/sources that confirm this?

Comment: Can't find any official references, but I've never seen or heard of an exception to this (not counting the multiple-character soulbound bug).

Comment: If there is a multi-character soulbound bug, doesn't this solve the initial problem of giving one class' default hood to another character?

Comment: It's solved but the bug is more of a side effect than the solution. As I said in my answer, you can transmute it to be soulbound to a new character. The bug is that the character that it was originally soulbound to will also be able to use it, as explained in the link in your comment on the question.